# Reliable way to extract values from (parse) Sympy result

Tags: python, parsing, sympy, symbolic-math, inequality

I'm using [SymPy, a Python library for symbolic mathematics](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html), to [reduce inequalities](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/inequalities.html?highlight=reduce%20inequalities) which are programmatically read in, for example

```
from sympy.solvers.inequalities import reduce_rational_inequalities

# In reality, these inequalities are read in programmatically
inequality1 = 'x - 0.5 >= 0.0'
inequality2 = '0.49 - x**2 >= 0.0'

listOfInequalities = [sympy.parse_expr(inequality1), sympy.parse_expr (inequality2)]

ReducedInequalities = reduce_rational_inequalities([listOfInequalities], x)
```

which produces the correct result corresponding to x being between 0.5 and 0.7:

> ```
> 0.5≤∧≤0.7
> ```

Or, expressed as a string:

```
strReducedInequalities = str(ReducedInequalities)
```

> ```
> \begin{equation*}(0.5 <= x) & (x <= 0.7)\end{equation*}
> ```

My question is, is there a reliable way to parse such a result to extract the constants 0.5 and 0.7? I can search the result strReducedInequalities, or possibly use regular expressions, to find the positions of for strings such as '(' and '<= x' to extract the 0.5 for example. But that seems brittle: If SymPy were to change its output formatting, the code could break.

What would be more reliable is a structured way to traverse the output, for example strReducedInequalities could be expressed as

```
[expression1, joiner, expression2]
```

where

- expression1 represents (0.5 <= x)
- joiner represents &
- expression2 represents (x <= 0.7)

and then expression1 might be broken down as

```
[constant, inequality_type, variable]
```

where

- constant = 0.5
- inequality_type represents <= (less than or equal to)
- variable = x

## Solution

Here's how I implemented the excellent solution from [@smichr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1089161/smichr):

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.core.relational import Relational
x = symbols('x')
eq = solve([x >= 0.5, x <= 0.7])
[(i.rhs, i.rel_op, i.lhs) for i in [i.canonical for i in eq.atoms(Relational)]]
```

Or using programatically-generated list approach in my original question:

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.core.relational import Relational
x = symbols('x')

# In reality, these inequalities are read in programmatically
inequality1 = 'x - 0.5 >= 0.0'
inequality2 = '0.49 - x**2 >= 0.0'

listOfInequalities = [parse_expr(inequality1), parse_expr (inequality2)]
eq = solve(listOfInequalities)
[(i.rhs, i.rel_op, i.lhs) for i in [i.canonical for i in eq.atoms(Relational)]]
```

Result using either approach:

> [(0.500000000000000, '>=', x), (0.700000000000000, '<=', x)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Relationals have been solved then there is a symbol on one side and the value on the other and the `canonical` method will put them in order so the symbol is on the left:

```
>>> eq
(1/2 <= x) & (x <= 7/10)
>>> [(i.rhs, i.rel_op, i.lhs) for i in [i.canonical for i in eq.atoms(Relational)]]
[(7/10, '<=', x), (1/2, '>=', x)]
```